# Login from shell in a Django site

Tags: django, curl, wkhtmltopdf

My 1.2.3 django site uses `contrib.auth` and my goal is to use the **wkhtmltopdf** command line to print a login-only page, [wkhtml can handle this situation](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg66008.html).

So I tested a login with **curl**, to be sure it's possible
The problem is that I always get a 403 CSRF (or cookie) protection errors.
I've tried to do disable CSRF with a second login view :

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

@csrf_exempt
def fakelogin(request, template_name='registration/login.html'):
    return login(request, template_name)
```

This new view works as expected. Then, as mentioned [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg65925.html) :

```
curl -c cookies.txt http://dev.local:8000/fakelogin/
curl -c cookies.txt -d login.txt http://dev.local:8000/fakelogin/
```

with the login.txt containing `username=Bob&password=secret&next=/page_to_print/id/`

But the 403 CSRF error still shows up (and I don't really know if it's related to CSRF or session cookies at his point...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable CSRF, just remove the CSRFMiddleWare in your settings.py file. But remember to put it back after your test.

You may want to use something like [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) in the future to test you page more easily, since it handles stuff like form sumission, link parsing, cookies and redirections for you.

Comment: Disabling CSRF is not an option. curl is just the simpler way to test the login success, I could use twill too, of course.

Comment: I suggested it (as a temporary measure) only because I read "I've tried to do disable CSRF with a second login view" in your question. Obviously you don't want to turn off that on prod. Twill is definitly the way to go as it's REALLY easy to use and can be installed with easy_install in one command.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I don't want to test my page, just be able to login via the shell, as I need to do this with wkhtml then.

Comment: Actually twills is not just a micro language. All twill commands have their Python counterparts, which mean you can easily create a script that go to a page, login and then ouput the HTML. You can then pipe it to wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: (après quelques essais très concluants) Merci de m'avoir fait découvrir twill, ça se loggue très bien, a contrario de curl, je renonce à savoir pourquoi :) Le pipe vers wkhtmltopdf aussi !

Comment: Great. BTW, french is not really going to be understood by anybody here.